# is there a way to populate an existing object from json using json.net based upon an interface

Tags: json.net

Looking for a way to do something like the following:

```
NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.Populate<IMyContract>(jsonStr, currentObj);
```

where the json.net engine would only attempt to populate the properties that are identified in the IMyContract.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to use a different tool than `json.net`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe u can use

```
PopulateObject(String, Object, JsonSerializerSettings)
```

And use your own JsonSerializerSettings. See: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm

Try to use one of the delegates to restrict the properties that are set yourself. That can be based on an Interface, using reflection.

I don't know any other way. If you don't get it with the JsonSerializerSettings you can always write your own PopulateObject method using the Json framework.